# If statement evaluating as true when it is not

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm assuming this is a trivial error, but I can not sort it out.

I have a simple script to find the width of the page in `em`, followed by an `if` statement, which for the sake of this question will just contain a `console.log`:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  var windowWidth = '';
  function getWidth() {
    windowWidth = $(window).width() / parseFloat($("body").css("font-size"));
  }
  window.addEventListener("load", getWidth);
  if (windowWidth < 40) {
    console.log("whaaaat");
  }
});
```

My `body` tag has a `font-size` of `16px`. This should not evaluate to true, but it does. When I call the `windowWidth` variable in the console, it return as greater than 40. Am I crazy?

Comment: well do you really expect that if to be evaluated after load? windowWidth is equal to `""` when that if runs. So the if is `if ("" < 40) {` The if statement needs to be in getWidth.

Comment: You've missed closing bracket after you `if` condition.

Comment: epascarello is correct, as far as I understand, on document `ready` the page already loaded, so it makes no sense to add a handler for a `load` event if load already took place.

Comment: @epascarello Of course. Thank you for the clarity. I do not need this functionality dynamically so I just removed the `eventListener` and called the function after declaring it. It is working now.

Comment: @derloopkat Yes redundancy at it's finest. Oops.

Comment: @Krusader That was just a copy, paste error. Thank you though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has several issues.

- First issue it that you are trying to compare a blank value to `40` since the `windowWidth` variable is yet to be populated when you compare it.
- The second issue is that you are using a `load` event inside a `$(document).ready` statement, which is unnecessary. `$(document).ready` is triggered after the page load anyway.

Here's a fixed version:

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
  var windowWidth = $(window).width() / parseFloat($("body").css("font-size"));
  
  console.log(windowWidth);
  
  if (windowWidth < 40)
    console.log("whaaaat");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you, I've since sorted it out. The `}` was just a copy error but I appreciate and understand the other two points.

Comment: @Tom Yep, removed that bullet from my answer.